# How to create a system that scans excel documents and stores data items in database?

Tags: excel, database, python-3.x

I am working on a software project for my course and I am supposed to make a software that makes a summary of the monthly salary of teachers by reading their daily subject routines. So, I thought instead of manual data entry, it would be better with a excel reader to scan for the items and enter it into the database.

Comment: Depending on the time you have, it seems entirely possible. Anyway, if you need help with a programming problem, you should present us a specific coding problem. Chech the [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and take the [tour page](https://stackoverflow.com/tour)

Answer (score 0):

Try using the pyexcel module for allowing python to interact with excel files. It is quite easy to use.

Docs: http://docs.pyexcel.org/en/latest/

Comment: the excel file to be handled would have merged cells, so would this module suffice??

Comment: Sure. This module is the best as a Python-Excel Integration API

Answer (score 0):

Try pandas [for more option](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_excel.html) and any database of your choice